# How to prevent duplicate payments in a shopping cart application built using servlets?

Tags: java, servlets

While developing a shopping cart application , 
lets assume that the user clicks on the payment button and request reaches server but the page is not refreshed due to slow network connection. Now if the user feels that the click has not responded and clicks the button for the second time how can we avoid a duplicate payment?

Comment: You could check if the order has already been processed then don't process it if it has...the second submission should check at the database level to see if it has been processed if it has then do nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: disable controls.
Better solution: add to form hidden uuid field of operation and check that operation is not processed before on server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an attribute in session object, whenever you get any payment request, first check the attribute exists for that session or not. If it does then discard the new payment request.

And after payment is made , remove that attribute from session.

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
if(session.getAttribute("Payment") == null){

   session.setAttribute("Payment");

   //Process your payment here

  session.removeAttribute("Payment");
}else{
   //Alert User that his payment is already in Process 
   //OR 
   //Do NOTHING
 }
```

Comment: ThnQ Anurag .. I would try this approach.

Comment: @sujith you are welcome, Let me know the results after you try it.